# How to show user "General Sync Settings" screen from my Android App?

Tags: android

I don't want to do something user don't want to, so if user has checked that he don't want to have any background data transfer (general sync settings) but in my application he has checked in prefs that he want from my application to do some background data transfer i want to show him some Warning Message and let him go (directly) from this point to general sync settings screen so he could change it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS) for your intent. You have to make sure before sending it that the intent will resolve though, as some devices may not be able to interpret that intent. If they can't, send [ACTION_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SETTINGS) instead, possibly with a note to the user telling them where the sync settings are (if your users aren't expected to be very tech savvy).